# How can I take a 2d array and then take every row and collapse it into the index of the maximum number?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array and I am trying to get the index and value of the largest number on the second axis. For example:

```
[
[1, 5, 3],
[6, 2, 4],
[4, 3, 5]
]
```

would return `[indexofmax, max]` for every line.

So:

```
[
[1, 5],
[0, 6],
[2, 5]
]
```

Comment: `[[i, max(inner)] for i, inner in enumerate(outer)]` should work

Comment: `i` will just give the index of the current row, not the index of the maximal value _in_ the row. @GreenCloakGuy

Comment: I think if you import NumPy and do numpy.amax(array_name) it will output what you want.

Comment: That is a list of lists, not a "2D array". [Python `array`s](https://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) are a different data structure, and neither lists nor arrays have a "2D" version. (Unless you are talking about _NumPy_ arrays, which is possible given your mention of "the second axis", but we're not going to assume that Please _tell us_ if you are using a library like that. Include the tag. See [ask].)

Comment: numpy is included

Comment: A comment is insufficient for critical information like this. Comments are throwaway. They can be deleted at any time, for any reason. Please [edit] your question to add the tag.

Comment: ok I've added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`, try with `argmax` and `take_along axis`:

```
# convert to numppy array if not already is
arr = np.array(arr)

idx = np.argmax(arr, axis=1)[..., None]     # the index of row maxmimum
np.hstack([idx, np.take_along_axis(arr, idx, axis=1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This line comprehension should do it:

```
def get_max_index(arr):
    return [[subarr.index(max(subarr)), max(subarr)] for subarr in arr]
```

Note - This will only return the first index of the largest number.

Comment: I tried this with my example array and it didn't work am I missing something? 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_max_index
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
ValueError: 5 is not in list`

Comment: sorry it won't let me add newlines for some reason

Comment: try again, made a mistake in orig